# Problem with double display of meshes and objects in edit mode

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, edit-mode, settings

When I switch to edit mode, as you can see in the picture, the mesh and the object are doubly visible.
[image]
The object is displayed with a little movement represented by bones, so I cannot access the hidden mesh beneath it.
Is there a display switch somewhere?
I may have accidentally changed the display settings without my noticing, as it did not display this way when I edited it before.
If anyone knows how to make the display setting mesh only, please advice.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have 2 objects? maybe share your mesh?

Comment: Yes, there is only one object. But this object is a "join" of two previously separate objects. Could that possibly be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't know, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable armature modifier in edit mode:

[image]

Or enable *On cage*:

[image]

Or use *Rest position* to disable bone movement temporarily:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is solved.